# The user could not sign in. The password supplied for the account was rejected

Tags: xcode

I am getting this error, which can be best represented by this image.

[image]

It is saying about the correct password in the Accounts preference pane. In the morning I did change the admin name and the password , as I am the new joinee to the team. Please help.

Comment: It's not clear what you want us to do.

Comment: what is the link of the Xcode and that of the Accounts preference pane where you change the username and password and give priviledges.

Comment: If you can login to https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action, then you should be able to login via Xcode.